# How to add x axis text in Bar Chart column

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I have done with chart preparation , but as per my requirement I want to add x axis value like inside the bar column. In My dummy data I have x axis as 'A', 'B','C','D'. How to move these letters inside bar column.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

     InitChart1();

  });
function InitChart() {
var barData = [{
        'x': 'A',
        'y': 50
      }, {
        'x': 'B',
        'y': 75
      }, {
        'x': 'C',
        'y': 110
      }, {
        'x': 'D',
        'y': 150
      }];

          var vis = d3.select('#visualisation1'),
            WIDTH = 500,
            HEIGHT = 500,
            MARGINS = {
              top: 20,
              right: 20,
              bottom: 20,
              left: 50
            },
            xRange = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right], 0.1).domain(barData.map(function (d) {
              return d.x;
            })),


            yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([0,
              d3.max(barData, function (d) {
                return d.y;
              })
            ]),

            xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(xRange)
              .tickSize(5)
              .tickSubdivide(true),

            yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(yRange)
              .tickSize(5)
              .orient("left")
              .tickSubdivide(true);


          vis.append('svg:g')
            .attr('class', 'x axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ')')
            .call(xAxis);

          vis.append('svg:g')
            .attr('class', 'y axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (MARGINS.left) + ',0)')
            .call(yAxis);

          vis.selectAll('rect')
            .data(barData)
            .enter()
            .append('rect')

            .attr('x', function (d) {
              return xRange(d.x);
            })
            .attr('y', function (d) {
              return yRange(d.y);
            }) 
            .attr('width', 75)
            .attr('height', function (d) {
              return ((HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) - yRange(d.y));
            })
            .attr('fill', 'grey');   
}</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `labels` rather then `axis ticks`. This tutorial should walk you through it.

http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/making-a-bar-chart